# Spark PageRank Tuning

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, pagerank

I am running a PageRank using scala+spark2.4 on yarn，but always failed after running several hours/jobs.

`--driver-memory 60G --driver-cores 4`

`--num-executors 250 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 32g`

input data:

- weightFile has 1000 .gz files,each 500MB, total 500GB
- linkFile has 1000 .gz fules, each 500MB， total 500GB

How should I change my code or spark configs?

````scala
    sc.setCheckpointDir(checkpointFile)

    val weightData = sc.textFile(weightFile).repartition(20000)
    val weightUrlData = weightData.map{line => val lines = line.split("\t"); (hash(lines(0)) , lines(0), lines(1).toFloat)}
    weightUrlData.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)

    var dataWeight = weightUrlData.map{x => (x._1,x._3)}
    dataWeight = dataWeight.reduceByKey{(a,b) => if(a > b) a else b}

    val dataUrl = weightUrlData.map{x => (x._1,x._2)}


    val totalZ = dataWeight.count.toFloat

    val sum1 = dataWeight.map(x => x._2).sum().toFloat
    dataWeight = dataWeight.map{x => (x._1,x._2/sum1)}



    val linkData = sc.textFile(linkFile).repartition(20000)
    val links  = linkData.map{line => val lines = line.split("\t");(hash(lines(0)),(hash(lines(1)),lines(2).toFloat))}.groupByKey()

    links.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY) 
    links.count()


    var ranks = links.mapValues(v => 1.0)


    for (i <- 1 to iters) {
      val contribs = links.join(ranks).values.flatMap{ case (urls, rank) =>
        urls.map(url => (url._1, url._2*rank))
      }
      contribs.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
      contribs.count()

      val ranksTmp = contribs.reduceByKey(_ + _).mapValues(0.85 * _)
      val Zranks = ranksTmp.map(x => x._2).sum()
      val Z = totalZ - Zranks
      println("total Z: " + totalZ + " Z: " + Z)
      val randnZ = dataWeight.map{x => (x._1,x._2*Z)}
      val rankResult = ranksTmp.rightOuterJoin(randnZ).map{case(a,(b,c)) => (a,b.getOrElse(0.0) + c) }
      ranks = ranks.join(rankResult).map{case(a,(b,c)) => (a,c)}
      if(i % 2 == 0) {
        ranks.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
        ranks.checkpoint()
        ranks.count()
      }else{
        ranks.count()
      }

      if(i == iters) {
        rankResult.map{case(a,b) => a.toString + "\t" + b.toString}.saveAsTextFile(outputFile)

        dataUrl.join(rankResult).values.map{case (a,b) => a + "\t" + b.toString}.saveAsTextFile(outputFile + "UrlAndWeight")
      }

```
````

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to guess why your code not working properly just by looking at it. A few years ago I implemented a Pagerank for ranking users in a social graph and it worked without a hitch for me - [link](https://github.com/artem0/spark-graphx/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/graphx/pagerank/SocialPageRankJob.scala#L8). Maybe it'd be helpful for you. Spark's Pregel interface runs pagerank [until convergence](https://github.com/artem0/spark-graphx/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/graphx/pagerank/SocialPageRankJob.scala#L13) or you may set [a fixed number of iterations](https://github.com/artem0/spark-graphx/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/graphx/pagerank/SocialPageRankJob.scala#L19).